# inline style in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

How to I add inline style in a .ctp file in CakePhp?

Comment: Please mention what version of php you use? Some more detail in your question would be nice?

Comment: "Inline" means something like `<div style="color: red;">`. What's keeping you from adding that to your HTML?

Answer (score 3):

You can treat a .ctp file almost exactly as you would .htm or .html

The extension enables CakePHP to see the file as a template. As such it can contain 100% HTML or 100% PHP or Javascript or CSS or any mix of anything you want that your server can parse.

That said, I would recommend that you keep your styles in a CSS file and include it like:

`echo $html->link('my_styles')`;

See http://book.cakephp.org/view/1437/css

Answer (score 2):

echo $this->Form->input("price",array("type"=>"text","label"=>false,"div"=>false,"style"=>"width:70px;height:20px;"));

Answer (score -2):

You can treat a .ctp file almost exactly as you would .htm or .html

```
 echo $this->Form->input('textarea', array('rows' => '5', 'cols' =>'5','style'=>array('background-color:#F99')));
```